# Wordpress pagination in static page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have the next problem: I try to use pagination in the index site but never works!

Mi code is:

```
if (get_query_var('paged')) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
        $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }
query_posts('category_name=news&order=DESC&paged=' .$paged);
```

And the link is:

```
localhost/web/page/2
```

The value of $paged always it's the same: 1.

I'm try to use the plugin wppage-navi but have the same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
                        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
                            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                        } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
                            $paged = get_query_var('page');
                        } else {
                            $paged = 1;
                        }
                        $q_cat = get_query_var('cat');
                        $cat = get_category($q_cat);
                        $catName = $cat->cat_ID;
                        $category = new WP_Query();
                        query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'producto', 'paged' => $paged, 'cat' => $catName ) );
                        if ( have_posts() ) : $count = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $count++;
                            get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
                        endwhile; else: ?>
                        <?php _e('sorry no posts', 'siddharta naranjo') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi! THanks for your response but have the same problem....my code its: if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
            $paged = get_query_var('page');
        } else {
            $paged = 1;
        }     
        echo $paged;        
        query_posts('category_name=noticias&posts_per_page=4&order=DESC&paged=' .$paged); and always have the same value: '1'

Comment: yo tengo corriendo el codigo en un sitio, ya revise el codigo y es correcto www.vidrio-aluminio.mx

Comment: Testing this code if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
                            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                        } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
                            $paged = get_query_var('page');
                        } else {
                            $paged = 1;
                        } in the index.php file, never works, always have "1" in $paged.....buuuuut, i try to put in header.php and works!!! Why???¿¿¿¿???? I'm never seen this O.o

Comment: This is not working for me even when I have included the code in header.php